# Create serial communication in NetBSD

Tags: serial-communication, rs485, netbsd

> I'm trying to create serial communication in NetBSD. This
>   communication will connect the computer with  a controller via RS-485.

The problem is that I don't know if it necessary some configuration or driver to do it.

Specifically, the communication will be through the RS-485 port. I've tried to use /dev/tty01, but there are no pulses in serial output.

Are there some configurations , drivers or codes necessary to open, send and receive serial data in NetBSD?

I didn't have sucess until now.

Thanks

Comment: How are you trying to connect to the device? Are you trying to do this in C or with a command such as cu?

Answer (score 0):

Nothing special needed.

If your serial is a real serial, then you could connect via:

```
# cu -l /dev/tty00
```

if your serial is a serial over USB then:

```
# cu -l /dev/ttyU0
```

However in both cases you have to be root, or change permissions on the device.

If the output is not visible, then adjust the speed with -s switch.